# How to parse a JSON string from a column with Pig

Tags: logging, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have tsv log files where a column is populated by a json string.

I want to parse that column with **JsonLoader** in a **Pig** script.
I saw many examples where **JsonLoader** is used in cases where each row is only a json string. I have other columns I want to skip and I don't know how to do that.

The file looks like this:

```
foo    bar    {"version":1; "type":"an event"; "count": 1}
foo    bar    {"version":1; "type":"another event"; "count": 1}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the JsonStringToMap UDF provided in Elephant Bird: https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/search?q=JsonStringToMap&ref=cmdform

Sample File:

```
foo     bar     {"version":1, "type":"an event", "count": 1}
foo     bar     {"version":1, "type":"another event", "count": 1}
```

Pig Script:

```
REGISTER /path/to/elephant-bird.jar;
DEFINE JsonStringToMap com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.JsonStringToMap();
raw = LOAD '/tmp/file.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (col1:chararray,col2:chararray,json_string:chararray);
parsed = FOREACH raw GENERATE col1,col2,JsonStringToMap(json_string);
ILLUSTRATE parsed; -- Just to show the output
```

Pre-processing (JSON as chararray/string):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| raw     | col1:chararray    | col2:chararray    | json_string:chararray                             | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         | foo               | bar               | {"version":1, "type":"another event", "count": 1} |
```

Post-processing (JSON as map):

---

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| parsed     | col1:chararray    | col2:chararray    | json:map(:chararray)                     | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            | foo               | bar               | {count=1, type=another event, version=1} | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the same question asked just two days ago: [How do you decode JSON in Pig that comes from a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874989/how-do-you-decode-json-in-pig-that-comes-from-a-column/24925809#24925809)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Elephantbird (Twitter's library for all things Hadoop) - they have a UDF called JsonStringToMap which does exactly what you need (takes a string and transforms it into a map).

Comment: Didn't want to use ElephantBird for that. Is there any other way? I tried to recompile EB but got stuck somewhere. Looks like it's not easy to build. #noob

Comment: Why not? You don't have to compile ElephantBird. You can look up the jars at http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.twitter.elephantbird%7Celephant-bird-pig%7C4.5%7Cjar