# How do you decode JSON in Pig that comes from a column?

Tags: apache-pig

There are numerous examples of how to use `JsonLoader()` to load JSON data with a schema from a file, but not from any sort of other output.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the JsonStringToMap UDF provided in Elephant Bird: https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/search?q=JsonStringToMap&ref=cmdform

Sample File:

```
foo     bar     {"version":1, "type":"an event", "count": 1}
foo     bar     {"version":1, "type":"another event", "count": 1}
```

Pig Script:

```
REGISTER /path/to/elephant-bird.jar;
DEFINE JsonStringToMap com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.JsonStringToMap();
raw = LOAD '/tmp/file.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (col1:chararray,col2:chararray,json_string:chararray);
parsed = FOREACH raw GENERATE col1,col2,JsonStringToMap(json_string);
ILLUSTRATE parsed; -- Just to show the output
```

Pre-processing (JSON as chararray/string):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| raw     | col1:chararray    | col2:chararray    | json_string:chararray                             | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         | foo               | bar               | {"version":1, "type":"another event", "count": 1} |
```

Post-processing (JSON as map):

---

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| parsed     | col1:chararray    | col2:chararray    | json:map(:chararray)                     | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            | foo               | bar               | {count=1, type=another event, version=1} | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This question is a duplicate of [How to parse a JSON string from a column with Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812265/how-to-parse-a-json-string-from-a-column-with-pig)